# Determine integers $x$ and $y$ that verify the relationship $x(x+3)(x+6)(x+9)+64=y^2$

Tags: inequality, integers

*question*

Determine integers $x$ and $y$ that verify the relationship

$x(x+3)(x+6)(x+9)+64=y^2$

*my idea*

I thought that we could write the equality this:

$x(x+3)(x+6)(x+9)+64=y^2 <=> x(x+3)(x+6)(x+9)=y^2-8^2=(y+8)(y-8)$

I don't know what to do forward but I thought of using intervals or the fact that a number can be negative or positive and let's analyze each case, but I don't go anywhere with my trys. Also modular arithmetic might be an idea. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: The eight solutions making $y=\pm8$ are almost obvious because the product of linear factors equal to $0$. Are there more solutions besides these eight ones? This is the problem to solve really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to rewrite $x(x+3)(x+6)(x+9)$ as a difference of two squares. $$x(x+3)(x+6)(x+9)=(x^2+9x)(x^2+9x+18)=(x^2+9x+9)^2-81$$
We can use this to get another difference of two squares. $$(x^2+9x+9)^2-81+64=y^2\\(x^2+9x+9)^2-y^2=(x^2+9x+9+y)(x^2+9x+9-y)=17$$
$x$ and $y$ are integers, so $x^2+9x+9+y$ and $x^2+9x+9-y$ are integers, so we can write them as factor pairs of $17$.
$$(x^2+9x+9+y,x^2+9x+9-y)=(1,17),(17,1),(-1,-17),(-17,-1)$$
From this we can obtain that $y=\pm8$, so $x(x+3)(x+6)(x+9)=0$. Therefore we get $8$ solutions.
$$(x,y)=(0,8),(0,-8),(-3,8),(-3,-8),(-6,8),(-6,-8),(-9,8),(-9,-8)$$

Answer (score 2):

As said in the above comment the $8$ solutions making $y=\pm8$ are evident. The proof of no more solutions is easy also. In fact we have putting $X=x^2+9x$ the equation
$$X^2+18X+(64-y^2)=0\Rightarrow X=-9\pm\sqrt{17+y^2}$$ so we need that $y^2+17=z^2$ and the only solution of this last equation is $(y,z)=(\pm8,\pm9)$ (other greater value of $y$ require the constant term be $\ge$ than $2\cdot9+1=19\gt17$).

Thus, no more solutions than the indicated eight.